# How to check parent & child category

Tags: categories

I just want to display a section in the parent category. And I want to display another section in the child category. How to do it?

```
      if ( is_category() ) {
          get_template_part( 'template-parts/banner/tab-1' , 'xcde' ); 
        } else {
           get_template_part( 'template-parts/banner/tab-2' , 'xcde' ); 
       ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your category template you can use `get_queried_object()` to get the current `WP_Term` object. From that you can check the `parent` property, which is 0, if it is a parent, or some integer, if it is a child term as it returns the parent term's ID.

```
$current_term = get_queried_object();
if ( $current_term->parent ) { 
    // child term
} else {
    // parent term
}
```

Comment: Thank you । It's working.